# Intersection of countably many sets

Tags: probability-theory

Here's a question I got as a homework assignment:

> Let $\{A_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,\infty}$ a sequence of events in the probability
>   space $(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$. Show that if $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=1$ for
>   all $i$ then $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i-1}^{\infty}A_i)=1$

So, as the equation is very obvious, I don't know how to prove it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I switched the tag from Probability to Probability theory

Comment: It may seem obvious, but it really does depend on the fact that you’re considering only countably many events. If there were uncountably many events, the probability of their intersection could even be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sequence of sets $B_{k+1} = A_{k+1} \bigcap B_k$, where $B_1 = A_1$. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(B_k) = 1$ and note that $$B_1 \supseteq B_2 \supseteq B_3 \supseteq \cdots$$ and $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$$

Recall the following result you should have proved for sequence of nested decreasing sets.

**Continuity from above**: If $C_k \downarrow C$, that is, $C_1 \supseteq C_2 \supseteq C_3 \cdots$ and $\displaystyle \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k = C$, then $\mathbb{P}(C_k) \downarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Can you please clarify the last line? I'm not familier with the arrow pointing down...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty}A_n=\Omega\setminus B
\quad
B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}(\Omega\setminus A_n)
\quad
\mathbb P(\Omega\setminus A_n)=0
\quad
\mathbb P(B)\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbb P(\Omega\setminus A_n)
$$

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what you already know about probability. If you know that the countable union of events of probability zero has probability zero then this is merely a case of applying DeMorgan laws:

Let $B_i$ be the complement of $A_i$, then $\Bbb P(B_i)=0$, then $\Bbb P(\bigcup B_i)=0$ as well, and by DeMorgan laws this is the same as saying $\Bbb P(\bigcap A_i)=1$.